# show a bootstrap modal which received on axios response after clicking the get modal button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, axios

here is exactly what i need
1 . when the user click the  button, the method is executed to get the bootstrap modal from the api.
then show to the user.
NB: initially the modal html should not be in the dom it is going to be created when the button is clicked.
i have accomplished this in jquery but not in vue.
Some code
1 . calling the modal(bootstrapvue btn)

```
  <b-button variant="success" @click="getAssignform">Assign</b-button>
```

script

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      assigntoteamform: '',
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {
 
    getAssignform() {

        this.axios({
          method: "get",
          url: "/assignig/new/456reqform",
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jkey"),
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            **this.assigntoteamform =response.data;**


          })
          .then((
   *$("#assigntohandmodal").modal("show")*  //this is what i try but this will work on the next click
          ))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error))
          .finally(() => (this.loading = false));

    }
};
</script>
```

binding the response to the html dom

```
<span v-html="assigntoteamform"></span>
```

this is the modal from the inspect element i can see that it is appended as expected .

```
<div id="assigntohandmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class=" card-header modal-header">

                <div class=" modal-title">Assign to a team</div>
                <button type="button" class="float-right close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center modal-body">
                <span id="form_result2"></span>

                <select class=" btn-success dynamic" name="team">
                     @foreach($list as $team)<option value="{{$team->team__id}}">{{$team->team__name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                     <div class="form-group" align="center">
                             <input type="hidden" name="handleret" id="handleret" />
                             <input type="hidden" name="handleret" id="handleret" />
                             <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" id="distotechnicia" class="subbb btn btn-success">Ok</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

once again it is working with html but in vue this " this.assigntoteamform =response.data;" is excuited after this "   $("#assigntohandmodal").modal("show")" i want the reverse .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, using jQuery in a Vue project is a bad practice. It will work, but this is just unnecessary overhead. Vue can do what jQuery does and arguably more. I see you are already using bootstrapVue, and therefore you don't need jQuery at all.

To answer your question, DOM updates in Vue are asynchronous. It means that when you assign `this.assigntoteamform` to `response.data`, and then proceed to show the modal, the DOM doesn't necessarily update in that order. There is a mechanism to wait for DOM updates before doing something, via [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

Replace what you have with

```js
export default {
  ....
  methods: {
    getAssignform() {
      this.axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/assignig/new/456reqform",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jkey"),
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.assigntoteamform =response.data;**
          this.$nextTick(() => { // waits for DOM to update after setting the value of this.assigntoteamform before opening the modal
            $("#assigntohandmodal").modal("show")
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    }
};
</script>
```

You can read more about Vue.$nextTick in this [article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/)